# Is it possible to change the java code files of external libraries downloaded by gradle in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, osmdroid

I am now working with `OSMDroid` and I want to modify two java files that was downloaded by gradle and then put into `External libraries` section. The two java files are : `MapTileFileArchiveProv.java` and `ZipFileArchive.java`. The are located in one of the packages in a classes.jar file. I am 90% sure that they are compiled and cannot be modified just by opening them in the editor, edit them and save them.

What are my options here?

Comment: I'd like to propose another approach - to inherit this classes.

Comment: just use a decompiler like this one http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: I would do that, but the fields are not protected.They are private.

Comment: If I decompile them, how can I put them back in their right places in external libraries?

Comment: also how I can I decompile them? I don't know their physical location

Comment: just add into you gradle file... dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:5.2'
}

Comment: Just extend the class

Answer (score 1):

Since OSMDroid is on GitHub you can fork it, modify whatever files, and build it yourself. You could then have gradle reference it directly as a project or put the output jar(s) into your project's "libs" dir and then add the following as a dependency:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

The downside of this is you'll have to maintain your fork by merging in future changesets periodically if you want to stay up to date with the master repo.